# Tag synonyms/merge request: [ati-catalyst], [catalyst] and [amd-catalyst]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Questions tagged [ati-catalyst](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ati-catalyst) and/or [catalyst](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/catalyst) are talking about the same thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Catalyst

I think they should be merged and/or made synonyms of each other. (Not really sure which tag should be made a synonym of which other tag.)

Also, due to [AMD retiring the ATI brand in favor of the 'AMD' name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATI_Technologies#History), [amd-catalyst](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amd-catalyst) should probably be also included in the merge or synonym creation with those tags.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.

Comment: Ok, I merged `catalyst` into `ati-catalyst`. Should we simply rename the ATI Catalyst tag to AMD Catalyst? And make a synonym from ATI Catalyst to AMD Catalyst?

Comment: @slhck yeah, I proceeded with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[slhck](https://meta.superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) [had](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6062/tag-synonyms-merge-request-ati-catalyst-catalyst-and-amd-catalyst#comment15534_6062) merged [catalyst](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/catalyst) and [ati-catalyst](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ati-catalyst), I went ahead and proceeded to merge [ati-catalyst](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ati-catalyst) with [amd-catalyst](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amd-catalyst) and made [ati-catalyst](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ati-catalyst) a synonym of [amd-catalyst](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amd-catalyst)